# Extending load cell wires for weight transmitter connection

Tags: amplifier, transmitter, load-cell

I have a load cell that I want to install in a certain location. I plan to connect its output to a load cell transmitter, which is approximately a meter away from the maximum length of the load cell wires.

Is it okay to extend the load cell wires to double the length? Can I use a control cable and simply join the wires to extend the length to connect it to the transmitter?

Comment: Usually and generally yes but, I underline the word generally. In a specific example, the answer could be no or, yes with some caveats.